# For displaying of audit logs, is it better to show date and time on separate lines?

Tags: tables, time

I have to design a page with a table for an audit log, and one of the columns is the **Timestamp**.
I am torn on how to handle this however, and I find examples of both on the web.

**A) Without  line break**

```
2020-12-20  01:59:20 GMT+8
```

or

**B) With line break**

```
2020-12-20
01:59:20 GMT+8
```

What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely go for option A. It makes it *much* easier to see that certain events happened close together, as can be seen from this example:

```
2020-12-20  02:45:30 GMT+8
2020-12-20  01:59:30 GMT+8
2020-12-20  01:59:26 GMT+8
2020-12-20  01:59:24 GMT+8
2020-12-20  01:59:20 GMT+8
2020-12-20  00:45:30 GMT+8
```

```
2020-12-20
02:45:30 GMT+8
2020-12-20
01:59:30 GMT+8
2020-12-20 
01:59:26 GMT+8
2020-12-20 
01:59:24 GMT+8
2020-12-20
01:59:20 GMT+8
2020-12-20
00:45:30 GMT+8
```

If you lack the horizontal space for this, consider dropping the timezone indication (but show it in the table footer), use a shorter date time format (e.g. "Dec 20, 01:59") or do use option B, but show the date only when it changes, e.g.

```
2020-12-21
08:15:10 GMT+8
2020-12-20
02:45:30 GMT+8
01:59:30 GMT+8
01:59:26 GMT+8
01:59:24 GMT+8
01:59:20 GMT+8
00:45:30 GMT+8
2020-12-19
16:15:10 GMT+8
```

The ability to quickly compare them matters less when showing only a single log, e.g. on a detail page or as a tooltip.